# How does JSON_EXTRACT work in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm having some trouble extracting some data from GA which carries some events and custom dimensions we are sending it.

I'm trying to use JSON_EXTRACT, and what I'd like to get is a column with all the values WHERE customDimension.index = index_number

Here's my code:

```
SELECT
  visitId,
  JSON_EXTRACT('index_number', '$.hits.customDimensions') as value
FROM
  FLATTEN(FLATTEN((
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([103264765.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP("2016-07-14"), DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()),-1,"DAY"))),hits),hits.customDimensions)
WHERE hits.eventInfo.eventAction = "EventName"
ORDER BY value DESC
```

Clarifications:

example index_number would be: '135'
example EventName would be: 'BookedFlight'

I plan to use the same approach to get other nested data, such as device browser, platform and so on, in order to relate it to our own data base data using visitorId

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How does JSON_EXTRACT work in BigQuery?

[BigQuery's JSON functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#jsonfunctions) give you the ability to find values within your stored JSON data, by using JSONPath-like expressions.

But for your example / use-case I don't see need in it at all!
Try below

```
SELECT
   visitId,
   hits.customDimensions.value AS value
FROM
  FLATTEN(FLATTEN((
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([103264765.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP("2016-07-14"), DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()),-1,"DAY"))),hits),hits.customDimensions)
WHERE hits.eventInfo.eventAction = "BookedFlight"
AND hits.customDimensions.index = 135
ORDER BY value DESC
```

in above simple case, you don't even need extra flattening, so below will work too

```
SELECT
   visitId,
   hits.customDimensions.value AS value
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([103264765.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP("2016-07-14"), DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()),-1,"DAY"))
WHERE hits.eventInfo.eventAction = "BookedFlight"
AND hits.customDimensions.index = 135
ORDER BY value DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail! Thats exactly what I've been using until now. The problem I have with that approach is that some of my events carry multiple parameters I'm interested in looking at. I have tried joining a bunch of subqueries querying different customDimension indxes, but once I get to three, it all starts going very slow. I want to learn to query values withing nested queries using JSON functions in order to access values stored in JSON objects in order to group by fullVisitorId or visitId. Another use case would be: what device is used per event? I feel that using JSON functions is much bettr

Comment: 1) so far, with all I see from you question and comments  - there is no use of JSON functions in your case! Please understand - JSON functions can be used when you have your json stored as a string in one field, which is not your case unless i am missing something!  i recommend you read again link in my answer to understand when and how json functions can be used. 2) I recommend you to post new question focusing on explaining what exactly your task is, what your current query is and what kind of issues are are experiencing. - with this we might be able to help you.